# AngularJS '=' binding and param="{{x}}" not compatible?

Tags: angularjs, data-binding

I have a directive with an isolated scope

```js
scope: {
  date: '@',
  values: '='
}
```

and I'm passing data from the controller through the html.

```html
<my-directive id='1' values='{{controllerValue}}' date='{{controllerDate}}'/>
```

and both variables are $scope variables in my controller. From what I have read, this is should work but it complains that the '{' bracket in the html is not expected. If I change the binding to one way:

```js
scope: {
  values: '@', 
  date: '@'
}
```

then it works. What am I doing wrong? Any insights would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: just remove the `{{ }}`

Comment: If I do that and then print it inside my directive's link function via **console.log($attr.value)** it outputs **controllerValue** rather than the contents

Comment: what's the output of `console.log(scope.values)` within the `link` function. can you show the whole codes for the directive? it's kind of hard to imagine how you wrote it.

Comment: Here is my [directive](https://jsfiddle.net/arvisto/eujzvc4r/1/) and the html I use to call it. The variables in the controller are all scope variables. As of right now, it displays everything correctly, however when I try to change the binding to two way '=' for **value** it tells me it does not like the '{'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`=` is two ways binding.It's required model rather than value .

That's why providing him model with `{{}}` won't work.

For him html should be `date='controllerDate'` instead of `date='{{controllerDate}}'`

`@` need value rather than model . That's why wapping model with `{{}}` providing him value.

Comment: Thanks you for your reply. I've tried removing the {{}} but doing so results in the directive receiving a string for both **value** and **date**.

Calling **console.log($attrs.date)** inside my directive's link function outputs **controllerDate**

Comment: can you provide a fiddle ? @Pablo

Comment: It works like this, but I need value to be a two-way bind. As soon as I change value: '@' to value: '=' the exception appears. It says the { in the html is not expected

Comment: code should be like this .. check date part both in html and link function http://jsfiddle.net/aiubian/6fLnb9rL/

Comment: Thanks! I was using the variables inside my directive wrong. I was trying to verify them as they came in through $attributes but when I used them with $scope.values or $scope.date like you just did everything worked. 

Many many thanks!